# error C2079: 'room::goldC' uses undefined class 'goldContainer'

Tags: visual-c++, c++11

i'm trying to create a room which has a goldContainer 
The goldContainer is defined in a separate .h file.
When i'm trying to compile it says

> error C2079: 'room::goldC' uses undefined class 'goldContainer'

The class voor room:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "screenSettings.h"
#include "floorplanPatch.h"
#include "floorplanPatchContainer.h"
#include "enemyContainer.h"
#include "goldContainer.h"
class goldContainer;
class room{
public:
    room(int themenr, floorplanPatchContainer &f);
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow &window);
    int getStartPoint();
    int getEndPoint();
    void addFloorplanPatch(int x, int y, int type, floorplanPatch *patch);
    bool isSolid(sf::Vector2f position);
    void addEnemy();
    static const int FLOOR_TEXTURE1 = 0;
    static const int FLOOR_TEXTURE2 = 1;
    static const int FLOOR_TEXTURE3 = 2;
    static const int FLOOR_TEXTURE4 = 3;
    static const int WALL = 4;
    static const int OBSTACLE = 5;
    static const int COSMETIC = 6;
    int floorplan[xAs][yAs];
    enemyContainer* getEnemyContainer();
    void room::addEnemy(int health);
private:
    enemyContainer ec;
    int startPoint = 1 + rand() % (yAs - 2);
    int endPoint = 1 + rand() % (yAs - 2);
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle{ sf::Vector2f{ tileSizeX, tileSizeY } };
    sf::Texture wall;
    sf::Texture obstacle;
    sf::Texture floor1;
    sf::Texture floor2;
    sf::Texture floor3;
    sf::Texture floor4;
    sf::Texture cosmetic;
    void drawBackgroundTile(sf::RenderWindow &window, int i, int x, int y);
    goldContainer goldC;
};
```

it has `class goldContainer;` on line 8 otherwise it generates error code 2146.

Could someone maybe explain how to solve this error and/or why this occurs.

```
#pragma once
#include "gold.h"
#include "sound.h"
#include "player.h"
class player;
class room;
class goldContainer{
public:
    goldContainer();
    ~goldContainer();
    void checkPickedUp(player &player);
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow &window);
    void addGold(int amount, sf::Vector2f position, sf::Vector2f size);
    void clearAllGold();

private:
    std::vector<gold* > goldDrops;
    sound goldPickup{ "sounds\\goldPickup.wav" };
};
```

I think it might be a circular depedency trough:

```
^->goldContainer->player->roomContainer->room->|
|<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-<-< v
```

Comment: You need to actually define it, not just declare it. It needs to know how large it is, to determine how large `room` is. Can you show us `goldContainer.h`, maybe it's a circular dependency.

Comment: i edited it to show the goldContainer

Comment: Then I'd say take `player.h` out of `goldContainer.h`, you forward declare it, and only take it by reference, so you don't actually need to include it.

Comment: okay i'm losing you how would you forward declare something? and maybe add it as a answer, so i can give you your earned points

Comment: you already did forward declare it with `class player;`. That tells the compiler that there is going to be a class with the name player but not how large an instance of it is or what its members are. But that is enough to pass and store references and pointers to it. Just remove the `#include "player.h"` from `goldContainer.h`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me show you the problem domain:

```
class Moon;

class Sun
{
    void Rotate(Moon);
};
```

Now, you implement `Sun::Rotate`, without giving any class declaration (**not** forward declaration):

```
void Sun::Rotate(Moon m) // Error C2027
{

}
```

What you can do:

- Ensure that before `Sun::Rotate` gets into compilation phase, `Moon` is declared (i.e. known to compiler by now). You need not to implement any method of `Moon`, just declare.

Example:

```
class Moon;

class Sun
{
     void Rotate(Moon);
};

// Let it come by now
class Moon
{
public:
   void PleaseRotate();
};

// Moon is known
void Sun::Rotate(Moon m)
{
   m.PleaseRotate(); // It need not to be implemented by now.
}
```

Note that `Moon::PleaseRotate` definition would be resolved by linker, and hence its implementation is not needed *before* `Sun::Rotate`.