# Why doesn't the compiler look at complete definition of a class?

Tags: c++

Code: This works

```
class smallDOUBLE;

class smallINT
{
private:
int val;   
public:
   smallINT():val(0){}
   smallINT(int i):val(i){}
   operator smallDOUBLE(); //comment this line
  //operator smallDOUBLE(){return val;}
};

class smallDOUBLE
{
private:
double val;
public:
   smallDOUBLE():val(0){}
   smallDOUBLE(double i):val(i){}
   operator smallINT() { return val;}
};

smallINT::operator smallDOUBLE(){return val;} //Comment this line.

int main()
{
  smallINT int1(10);
  smallDOUBLE DBL1(123.22);
  smallINT int2 = DBL1;
  smallDOUBLE DBL2 = int1;
}
```

But when I comment  `smallINT::operator smallDOUBLE(){return val;}` , `operator smallDOUBLE();`
  and uncomment

`operator smallDOUBLE(){return val;}` compiler throws error saying

[image]

why doesn't the compiler look at the complete definition of the class if it is forward declared and find the definition for every members of the class, so that the programmer doesn't have to explicitly define the member somewhere outside?

What prevents a compiler from doing so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765463/error-c2079-roomgoldc-uses-undefined-class-goldcontainer/26786626#26786626

Comment: why is this question tagged `compiler-construction`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point where you're trying to convert a number to `smallDOUBLE`, nothing more is known about that class than that it is a class.

For all the compiler knows there may not be any relevant constructor to do the job.

So why doesn't the compiler just leave that question open and fill in with proper code when it finally encounters the `smallDOUBLE` class definition? Or do a second pass through the source code? Well, for one, that definition could be in a different translation unit, which would then require code generation at link time, which is not unheard of today (think e.g. global optimization) but which C and C++ are designed to not require. That's not just a technical problem. If it were done, then you would not get any real error message (oh, I finally discovered that there's no appropriate constructor) until link time.

Comment: For the record, Visual Age C++ does look at all of the definitions (or at least did).  Which is definitely not standard conform (since you don't need any includes, and can see classes and functions which aren't part of the current translation unit); most programmers I know consider this a mis-feature (and I think Visual Age ended up at least adding an option to suppress it).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that. The Wikipedia article is unclear on whether Visual Age C++ is still extant as of 2014 (it was there as late as 2011), but [IBM's web page for it](http://www-306.ibm.com/software/awdtools/vacpp/) now redirects to IBM XL C/C++.

Comment: Yes.  My information goes back to around twenty years ago.  I have no idea what the current status is, although the redirection to Xl makes me think that IBM has reverted to more classical technologies.